# How to convert single char to double

Tags: c++

I try to create a program that can evaluate simple math expression like "4+4". The expression is given from the user.

The program saves it in a `char*` and then searches for binary operation (+,-,*,:) and does the operation.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to convert the **single** `char` into a `double` value.

I know there is the `atof` function but I want to convert single `char`.

There is a way to do that without creating a `char*`?

Comment: If it is a single char, why don't you explicitly check the digit? Or use that as an int (ASCII table), '0' through '9' are represented as 48 to 57...

Comment: `The program saves it in a char*` -- That doesn't happen.  You are saving the characters into a buffer, not into a pointer.

Comment: You're question isn't very clear. Do you mean `'0' => 0` ... `'9' => 9` and all other non-digit characters are errors?

Comment: _@Erika_ Well, I gave you an answer how to do that for a single `char`. Though, how do you plan to handle an expression like "40+40" from user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `char` usually represents a character. However, a single `char` is simply an integer in range of at least [-127,+127] (signed version) or at least [0,255] (unsigned version).

If you obtained a character looking as a digit, the value stored in it is an ASCII number representing it. Digits start at code 48 (for zero) and go up incrementally till code 57 (for nine). Thus, if you take the code and subtract 48, you get the integer value. From there, converting it to double is a matter of casting.

Thus:

```
char digit = ...
double value = double(digit - 48);
```

or even better, for convenience:

```
char digit = ...
double value = double(digit - '0'); //'0' has a built-in value 48
```

Comment: `digit - '0''` is portable; it doesn't assume ASCII, and will work for **any** character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a way to do that without creating a char* ???

Sure. You can extract the digit number from a single `char` as follows:

```
char c = '4';
double d = c - '0'; 
        // ^^^^^^^ this expression results in a numeric value that can be converted
        //         to double
```

---

This uses the circumstance that certain character tables like [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encode the digits in a continuous set of values starting at `'0'`.

Comment: Assuming char is an ASCII value from '0' to '9'.  Probably safe here, but OP's post doesn't inspire a ton of confidence...